# authorized_keys setup in ansible for a user

Tags: ansible

Im trying to create a user and add to the authorized_keys file.

Here is the ansible code when I try to run I get the following error:

> ERROR! this task 'authorized_key' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: command, win_command, shell, win_shell, script, include, include_vars, add_host, group_by, set_fact, raw, meta

```
- name: Adding user {{ user }}  
  user: name={{ user }}
        group={{ group }}
        shell=/bin/bash
        password=${password}
        groups=sudo
        append=yes
        generate_ssh_key=yes
        ssh_key_bits=2048
        ssh_key_file=.ssh/id_rsa

- name: Authorized keys
  authorized_key:
        user={{ user }}
        state=present
        manage_dir= yes
        key="{{ lookup('file', '/home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with the space here: `manage_dir= yes`.

Use pure YAML syntax to prevent different kind of issues with `key=value` syntax.

```
- name: Authorized keys
  authorized_key:
    user: "{{ user }}"
    state: present
    manage_dir: yes
    key: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/vivek/.ssh/id_rsa.pub') }}"
```